# Location by code. C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, location

I would like to change the Y location for a dataGridView to 75, I am trying to move it up at the click of a button.

have already tried

```
this.dataGridView1.Location = new Point(
 this.dataGridView1.Location.X,
 this.dataGridView1.Location.Y
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you meant:

```
this.dataGridView1.Location = new Point(this.dataGridView1.Location.X, 75);
```

Answer (score 2):

More shortly
`this.dataGridView1.Top = 75;`

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
dataGridView1.Left = 58; //X coordinate
dataGridView1.Top  = 57; //Y coordinate
```